# Reading and interpreting memory page file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, vmware, virtual-machine

I need to analyse some malware that I have on a vmware image (vmware is a virtual machine), in particular I need to do a full dump of a certain process. I know that vmware,on pausing, writes the whole RAM into a .vmem file. The platform the image is taken of is Windows XP. I know that there are certain tools that do this but they are mostly closed source or don't work for Windows XP. I need it to be done in reasonable time (under one second if that is possible somehow) and to run it from my own C++ program, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the ideas in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939599/is-it-possible-to-unpage-all-memory-in-windows) can be of help if you want to dump from within the running system.

Comment: I don't want to dump it in the system itself, I want to dump it from the page-file while the virtual system is frozen.

Comment: Hm, I'd say that'll be Very Hard at the very least :-)

Comment: surely it would be easier to analyze the malware in a closed system meant for this, something like IDA and Bochs? http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/index.shtml

Comment: @Necrolis thanks for the hint I will think about it if there are no useful answers :-)

Comment: You realize this won't work at all if the system has Swap turned on, right?  The entire malware image could be on disk even while running, at the very least some pieces of it probably would be.  Use a debugger on the system, or write your own simple debugger to run inside the VM and dump the program's entire address space to disk.  That is pretty trivial to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking to interact with processes and their memory from a suspended VM.

Give some forensic tools a shot. This one looks promising:

http://code.google.com/p/volatility/