# How can I swap windows 7 paged memory back into ram after memory is freed?

Tags: memory, memory-management

I typically use about 5GB of RAM on my workstation at work. I normally have to run a few instances of matlab at a time, each running simulink simulations. These use a total of about 4-6GB RAM. When these are active, windows dumps memory in RAM to the page file to free space for matlab.

The problem is when the simulations are over, 2-3GB stays in the page file and slows the systems DRAMATICALLY. This computer has AWFUL disk read and write performance.

Is there a way I can move the paged memory back over to ram to avoid this performance hit?

Right now I am required to restart my computer when I am done running the simulations to speed it up again.

I have 8GB RAM with a 12GB page file.

Comment: Other than including the word matlab, this question doesnt seem to have anything to do with programming

Comment: I could always write something to automate transferring the paged memory. That's what I was intending with this question. If there are already tools written, it's even better.

Answer (score 1):

Check out

[Is it possible to unpage all memory in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939599/is-it-possible-to-unpage-all-memory-in-windows)

The answer given by @KerrekSB seems to include some code for doing it.  But the long and short of it is that you need to walk the list of processes, then walk the list of memory allocations for those processes, reading as you go.